# C# Null check handling failing

Tags: c#

I am struggling to handle a null check in-line, can someone help identify where I am going wrong please?

When passing in a null intentionally, I want to handle it and want x to be an empty string.  If it isn't Null, I want it to be the value set.

```
var x = string.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewModel.OccupationRefer.ToString()) ? string.Empty : ViewModel.OccupationRefer.ToString();
```

The above with a null passed into ViewModel.OccupationRefer, throws a null exception.

Comment: What type is `ViewModel.OccupationRefer`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var x = ViewModel?.OccupationRefer?.ToString() ?? "";
```

This uses null-conditional (`?.`) and null-coalescing (`??`) operations so that if either `ViewModel` or `ViewModel.OccupationRefer` are `null`, or if the `ToString()` returns `null`: you get `""`

Comment: Ah, that makes sense!!  Thx will accept shortly.

Answer (score 4):

If `ViewModel.OccupationRefer` is null then you can't call `ToString()` on it. You need to check it for null, not the output of `ToString()`.